# Convolutions of singular measure on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking for examples of measures $m_1,..., m_k$, $k>1$, on $\mathbb R$ that are singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure and there convolution is absolutely continuous. There are examples on this forum, I have read them, but I am interested also in others.

Comment: Can you also share the link to "examples on this forum"?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be iid Bernoulli(1/2) random variables.  Let
$Y_o = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{1-2n} X_{2n-1}$ and $Y_e = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-2n} X_{2n}$.  The distributions of the random variables $Y_o$ and $Y_e$ are supported 
on two Cantor-type sets (the numbers $x \in [0,1]$ whose binary expansion has all zeros in the even and odd positions respectively) which have Lebesgue measure $0$, so they are singular.  But the convolution of these distributions is the distribution of $Y_o + Y_e = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-2n} X_n$, which is uniform on $[0,1]$.